# ifelse rows the same in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df<-data.frame(A=c(NA,1,2,3,4),B=c(NA,5,NA,3,4),C=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,4))
> df
   A  B  C
1 NA NA NA
2  1  5 NA
3  2 NA NA
4  3  3 NA
5  4  4  4
```

I am trying to create a "D" column based on the row values in df, where D gets an NA if the values in the row are different (i.e. row 2) or all NAs (i.e. row 1), and the value in the row if the values in that row are the same, excluding NAs (i.e. rows 3, 4, 5). This would produce a vector and dataframe that looks like this:

```
> df$D<-c(NA,NA,2,3,4)
> df
   A  B  C  D
1 NA NA NA NA
2  1  5 NA NA
3  2 NA NA  2
4  3  3 NA  3
5  4  4  4  4
```

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `apply()` to do calculation for each row and then use `unique()` and `!is.na()`. With `!is.na()` you select values that are not NA. With `unique()` you get unique values and then with `length()` get number of unique values. If number is 1 then use first non NA value, if not then NA.

```
df$D<-apply(df,1,function(x) 
  ifelse(length(unique(x[!is.na(x)]))==1,x[!is.na(x)][1],NA))
```

Comment: alternatively, instead of checking whether `length(unique(x))==1` you can check whether `sd(x, na.rm=T)==0`.

Comment: +1 @nico Yes, that would be good alternative.

Comment: Why didn't I think of unique (a duh moment) +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible approach:

```
FUN <- function(x) {
    no.na <- x[!is.na(x)]
    len <- length(no.na)
    if (len == 0) return(NA)
    if (len == 1) return(no.na) 
    runs <- rle(no.na)[[2]]
    if(length(runs) > 1) return(NA)
    runs
}

df$D <- apply(df, 1, FUN)

## > df
##    A  B  C  D
## 1 NA NA NA NA
## 2  1  5 NA NA
## 3  2 NA NA  2
## 4  3  3 NA  3
## 5  4  4  4  4
```